# How to format date with date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

I've been trying to format a date using **date-fns** but I keep failing. Basically I have it working just fine with momentJS but not with date-fns:

Here's my date:

```
"10-13-20" // month, day, and year
```

Now with momentJS it works just fine like this:

```
let result = moment("10-13-20", 'MM-DD-YY').format()
// result = "2020-10-13T00:00:00-06:00"
```

So I'm trying to do the same using **date-fns** but no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

```
let result = format(new Date("10-13-20"), 'MM-DD-YY') // Not working
```

Comment: `new Date("10-13-20")` returns an invalid Date in Firefox and Safari at least. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As you can see, with `moment` lib, we need 2 steps to get the result: parse string to `Date` object, then format date object to string.

Your code - `format(new Date("10-13-20"), 'MM-DD-YY')` is `format` step, try convert a date object to a string with format template is `MM-DD-YY`. But your date object is not correct.

The solution is to do the same as with `moment` lib:

1. Parse date string to date object. Use [parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.6/docs/parse)

   ```
   const dateString = '10-13-20';
   const date = parse(dateString, 'MM-dd-yy', new Date()) // not MM-DD-YY
   ```
2. Format date object to result string. Use [format](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format)

   ```
   const result = format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx")
   console.log(result)
   ```

   Result will be like (the same with moment's result in my timezone):

   ```
    2020-10-13T00:00:00.000+09:00
   ```

Answer (score 13):

```
const date = "2021-12-20"
console.log(format(parseISO(date), "dd-MM-yyyy"));
// output: 20-12-2021
```

Comment: parseISO(date) is giving error